# Select middle value for nth rows in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating new dataframe which should contain an only middle value (not Median!!) for every nth rows, however my code doesn't work!

I've tried several approaches through pandas or simple Python but I always fail.

```
       value   date        index
   14  40      1983-07-15  14
   15  86      1983-07-16  15
   16  12      1983-07-17  16
   17  78      1983-07-18  17
   18  69      1983-07-19  18
   19  78      1983-07-20  19
   20  45      1983-07-21  20
   21  47      1983-07-22  21
   22  48      1983-07-23  22 
   23  .....    .........  ..
```

```
   RSDF5 = RSDF4.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='15D', key='DATE')).[int(len(RSDF5)//2)].reset_index()
```

I know that the code is wrong and I am completely out of ideas!

```
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: middle value of N rows or of N days? May be different unless you always have one day per row and no holes

Comment: can u give me an example what do you expect for your answer to be?

Comment: Yeah it is supposed that there are no holes in dates, however it should be interesting to see it by index. I know only the freq='15D' approach.

Comment: Add a `iloc` between the dot and `[int(len(RSDF5)//2)]` ?

Comment: @fmarm AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'iloc' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution based on indexes.

`df` is your original dataframe, N is the number of rows you want to group (assumed to be ad odd number, so there is a unique middle row).

```
df2 = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//N).apply(lambda x : x.iloc[len(x)//2])
```

Be aware that if the total number or rows is not divisible by N, the last group is shorter (you still get its middle value, though).
If N is an even number, you get the central row closer to the end of the group: for example, if N=6, you get the 4th row of each group of 6 rows.